# How to send sms to user's phone number in kotlin compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, sms

I am trying to send an sms consisting of 4 digits that I randomly created to the phone number entered by the user in an application, to see if the phone number really belongs to that person. When I researched this on the internet, I came across a few things, these are the SMS User Consent API and the SMS Retriever API, but according to what I researched, they are not useful for sending sms. The purpose of the SMS Retriever API is to receive and automatically read the sent sms, and the purpose of the SMS User Consent API is to get permission from the user. Since I've never done anything like this before, I couldn't find which one among all the things on the internet was suitable and I was confused. Now I am sending an sms to the phone that the user enters using the sms manager library, but it did not fully satisfy me.

The reasons why I don't like it are:

1. According to an article I read, google play has removed most applications that ask for sms permission from google play. The reason google play did this was to increase the scrutiny of things that recently asked for sms permission or violated the user's privacy. Therefore, when I upload this application to google play in the future, I do not want to face any problems or removal from google play.
2. I need to do this because I need to send this sms to the user's phone, but sending sms has the potential to violate the user's privacy. I need the user's permission for this (if it does not happen without it, I would appreciate it if you tell me how it is and is it a good method). In my case it's likely. If the user doesn't give permission, I need to ask for permission until the user gives permission. How user friendly is that? Or is it a good method? I will share the necessary parts of my codes below

my application consists of many screens, but I think only 2 screens are relevant to this question. The first screen is the screen where I get the user's phone number, name, surname, password, date of birth, and the user registers on this screen. There is a button on this screen, that is, on the registration screen, if the user has entered the input values ​​in the correct format, there are 4 boxes where he enters the sms received on the next screen, that is, the phone number he entered. On these screens, I thought it would be more logical to ask the user for sms permission on the screen where I will receive the phone number, that is, on the registration screen. By the way, I read that it is also with firebase, but I have no business with firebase. I just want to send an sms consisting of 4-digit random numbers to the phone the user enters and receive it and enter it on the next screen.

**My registration screen**

```
@Composable
fun UserFormScreenRoute(
    navHostController: NavHostController,
    sharedViewModel: SharedViewModel,
    viewModel: UserFormViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {

    val state by viewModel.state.collectAsState()

    UserFormScreen(
        navHostController = navHostController,
        sharedViewModel = sharedViewModel,
        state = state,
        sendMessage = viewModel::sendMessage,
        requestSmsPermission = viewModel::requestSmsPermission,
    )

}


      @Composable
    fun UserFormScreen(
        
    ) {
    
        val context = LocalContext.current
    
        val activity = context as Activity
 
        val result = requestSmsPermission(activity, 123)
    
        if (result == false) {
            requestSmsPermission(activity, 123)
    
        }
 
        Scaffold(
            topBar = {
                BackPopUp(
                    navController = navHostController,
                    route = RegisterScreen.SignUpHealthyLifeStyleGoalsScreen.route
                )
            },
            backgroundColor = Color.Transparent
        ) {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize(),
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
            ) {
    
                    DYTLoginAndContinueButton(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .padding(16.dp),
                        text = stringResource(id = R.string.devam),
                        navController = navHostController,
                        route = RegisterScreen.SignUpVerificationPhoneCodeScreen.route,
                        enabled = buttonEnabled(state)
                    ) {
    
                        val smsCode = (1000..9999).random()
    
                        startSMSRetrieverClient(context)
    
                        val result = requestSmsPermission(activity, 123)
                        if (result)
                            sendMessage(getFullPhoneNumber(), "asdasd", smsCode)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

on this screen, as soon as the screen loads, I call it once and if the user has not given sms permission before, I want permission, but this of course works only once.

```
   val activity = context as Activity
  
   val result = requestSmsPermission(activity, 123)
     
   if (result == false) {
       requestSmsPermission(activity, 123)
     
       }
```

**my registration screen view model**

```
@HiltViewModel
class UserFormViewModel @Inject constructor(
   

) : ViewModel() {

 

    fun requestSmsPermission(activity: Activity, requestCode: Int): Boolean {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (activity.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return true
            } else {
                activity.requestPermissions(arrayOf(Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS), requestCode)
                return false
            }
        } else {
            return true
        }
    }

    fun sendMessage(phoneNumber:String, message:String, smsCode:Int):String {

        try {
            val smsManager: SmsManager = SmsManager.getDefault()
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, "$smsCode $message", null, null)
            return "success"
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            return e.localizedMessage
        }

    }
}


}
```

**the next screen from the registration screen**

```
@Composable
fun VerificationPhoneCodeRoute(
    navHostController: NavHostController,
    viewModel: VerificationPhoneCodeViewModel = hiltViewModel()) {


    val state by viewModel.state.collectAsState()

    VerificationPhoneCodeScreen(
        navHostController = navHostController,
        state = state,
        onChangeOtpValue = viewModel::onChangeOtpValue)
}


@Composable
fun VerificationPhoneCodeScreen(
    navHostController: NavHostController,
    state:VerificationPhoneCodeScreenState,
    onChangeOtpValue:(String)->Unit
) {



    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            BackPopUp(navController = navHostController, route = null)
        },
        backgroundColor = Color.Transparent
    ) {

        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top
        ) {

            Text(
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp),
                text = stringResource(id = R.string.telefonuna_gelen_kodu_asagidaki_alana_giriniz),
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.subtitle1
            )

            OtpTextField(
                otpText = state.otpValue,
                onOtpTextChange = { value, otpInputFilled ->
                    onChangeOtpValue(value)
                }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

**otpTextfield**

```
@Composable
fun OtpTextField(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    otpText: String,
    otpCount: Int = 4,
    onOtpTextChange: (String, Boolean) -> Unit
) {

    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        if (otpText.length > otpCount) {
            throw IllegalArgumentException("Otp text value must not have more than otpCount: $otpCount characters")
        }
    }

    BasicTextField(
        modifier = modifier,
        value = TextFieldValue(otpText, selection = TextRange(otpText.length)),
        onValueChange = {
            if (it.text.length <= otpCount) {
                onOtpTextChange.invoke(it.text, it.text.length == otpCount)
            }
        },
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.NumberPassword),
        decorationBox = {
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().padding(15.dp),
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
            ) {
                repeat(otpCount) { index ->
                    CharView(
                        index = index,
                        text = otpText
                    )
                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(8.dp))
                }
            }
        }
    )
}

@Composable
private fun CharView(
    index: Int,
    text: String
) {
    val isFocused = text.length == index
    val char = when {
        index == text.length -> "0"
        index > text.length -> ""
        else -> text[index].toString()
    }
    Text(
        modifier = Modifier
            .size(50.dp, 60.dp)
            .border(
                2.dp, when {
                    isFocused -> MaterialTheme.colors.DYTThemeColor
                    else -> MaterialTheme.colors.grayColor
                }, RoundedCornerShape(8.dp)
            )
            .padding(2.dp)
            .offset(y = 15.dp),
        text = char,
        style = MaterialTheme.typography.h4,
        color = MaterialTheme.colors.DYTThemeColor,
        textAlign = TextAlign.Center
    )
}
```

I know, I explained it in detail, it may seem complicated, so I'm sorry, I just made it for clarity.

Comment: "I just want to send an sms consisting of 4-digit random numbers to the phone the user enters and receive it and enter it on the next screen" -- why would the *user* want you to do this?

Comment: to authenticate the user's phone

Comment: No, that is why *you* want to do this. Why does the *user* want you to do this? Note that if you use `ACTION_SENDTO` with an `smsto:` `Uri`, you do not need a permission -- the user will be in control of the SMS client and can elect to send (or not send) the message.

Comment: I don't understand because Don't we need to ask permission from the user for sms anyway? and sorry for not knowing how ACTION_SENDTO works. what I understand is that the user can control whether the sms is sent or not.